# How to perferm different action depending on user input

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to make a really simple game (even without an interface). You are supposed to type what action would you like to do attack, heavy and light or block). But "enemy" responds only to "light" action. What is the problem?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hp = 10, enemy_hp = 10;
        String attack = "attack";
        String block = "block";
        String heavy = "heavy";
        String light = "light";
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (enemy_hp > 0 && hp > 0) {
            System.out.println("It is your turn, attack (heavy or light) or try to block");
            int your_block_chance1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4); //Chance to block an attack
            int enemy_block_chance1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
            String action = userInput.next();
            if (action.equals(attack)) { //attack
                System.out.print("You attacked your enemy and ");
                if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("he blocked it");
                } else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0) {
                    enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 3;
                    System.out.println("managed to hit, now his hp is " + enemy_hp);
                }
            } else if (action.equals(light)) { //light attack
                System.out.print("You want to do a light attack");
                if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(" but he blocked it");
                } else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0) {
                    enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 1;
                    System.out.println(" and you managed to hit him, now his hp is " + enemy_hp);
                } else if (action.equals(block)) { //block
                    System.out.println("You dicided to block and rest");
                    your_block_chance1 = (int)(Math.random() * 1);
                    hp++;
                } else if (action.equals(heavy)) { //heavy attack
                    System.out.print("You went for a heavy attack");
                    int heavy_attack_chance = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
                    if (heavy_attack_chance == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" but failed");
                    } else if (heavy_attack_chance != 1) {
                        if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                            System.out.println(" but he blocked it");
                        } else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0) {
                            enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 6;
                            System.out.println(" and you managed to hit you really hard, now his hp is " + enemy_hp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("It is your enemy turn, he decided to "); //enemy turn 
                int enemy_action2 = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
                if (enemy_action2 == 1) {
                    System.out.print("attack you,"); //attack
                    if (your_block_chance1 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                    } else if (your_block_chance1 != 0) {
                        hp = hp - 3;
                        System.out.println(" and you didn't block it, now your hp is " + hp);

                    }
                } else if (enemy_action2 == 0) { //heavy attack
                    System.out.print("do a heavy attack");
                    int heavy_attack_chance = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
                    if (heavy_attack_chance == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" but failed");
                    } else if (heavy_attack_chance != 1) {
                        if (your_block_chance1 == 0) {
                            System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                        } else if (your_block_chance1 != 0) {
                            hp = hp - 6;
                            System.out.println(" and he managed to hit you really hard, now your hp is " + hp);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (enemy_action2 == 3) { //light attack
                    System.out.print("do a light attack");
                    if (your_block_chance1 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                    } else if (your_block_chance1 != 0) {
                        hp = hp - 1;
                        System.out.println(" and he managed to hit you, now your hp is " + hp);
                    }
                } else if (enemy_action2 == 2) { //block
                    System.out.println("block and rest");
                    enemy_hp++;
                }
            }
            if (hp <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You failed");
            } else if (enemy_hp <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You won!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by properly indenting your code; any IDE and most text editors will do this for you. It's quite difficult to follow your blocking.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It is very difficult to read it in its current form

Comment: Sorry about that. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misplaced brackets:
I have removed end bracket `}` from the end and added one just before `} else if (action.equals(heavy)) {`

Check this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hp = 10, enemy_hp = 10;
    String attack = "attack";
    String block = "block";
    String heavy = "heavy";
    String light = "light";
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (enemy_hp > 0 && hp > 0) {
        System.out.println("It is your turn, attack (heavy or light) or try to block");
        int your_block_chance1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4); //Chance to block an attack
        int enemy_block_chance1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
        String action = userInput.next();
        if (action.equals(attack)) { //attack
            System.out.print("You attacked your enemy and ");
            if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                System.out.println("he blocked it");
            } else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0) {
                enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 3;
                System.out.println("managed to hit, now his hp is " + enemy_hp);
            }
        } else if (action.equals(light)) { //light attack
            System.out.print("You want to do a light attack");
            if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                System.out.println(" but he blocked it");
            } else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0) {
                enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 1;
                System.out.println(" and you managed to hit him, now his hp is " + enemy_hp);
            }
        } else if (action.equals(block)) { //block
                System.out.println("You dicided to block and rest");
                your_block_chance1 = (int)(Math.random() * 1);
                hp++;
        } else if (action.equals(heavy)) { //heavy attack
                System.out.print("You went for a heavy attack");
                int heavy_attack_chance = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
                if (heavy_attack_chance == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" but failed");
                } else if (heavy_attack_chance != 1) {
                    if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(" but he blocked it");
                    } else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0) {
                        enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 6;
                        System.out.println(" and you managed to hit you really hard, now his hp is " + enemy_hp);
                    }
                }
        }
            System.out.print("It is your enemy turn, he decided to "); //enemy turn 
            int enemy_action2 = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
            if (enemy_action2 == 1) {
                System.out.print("attack you,"); //attack
                if (your_block_chance1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                } else if (your_block_chance1 != 0) {
                    hp = hp - 3;
                    System.out.println(" and you didn't block it, now your hp is " + hp);

                }
            } else if (enemy_action2 == 0) { //heavy attack
                System.out.print("do a heavy attack");
                int heavy_attack_chance = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
                if (heavy_attack_chance == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" but failed");
                } else if (heavy_attack_chance != 1) {
                    if (your_block_chance1 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                    } else if (your_block_chance1 != 0) {
                        hp = hp - 6;
                        System.out.println(" and he managed to hit you really hard, now your hp is " + hp);
                    }
                }
            } else if (enemy_action2 == 3) { //light attack
                System.out.print("do a light attack");
                if (your_block_chance1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                } else if (your_block_chance1 != 0) {
                    hp = hp - 1;
                    System.out.println(" and he managed to hit you, now your hp is " + hp);
                }
            } else if (enemy_action2 == 2) { //block
                System.out.println("block and rest");
                enemy_hp++;
            }
        }
        if (hp <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You failed");
        } else if (enemy_hp <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You won!");
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: @Napoleon Sraf: See edit. Input "block" is also taken care.

Answer (score 1):

Here you get an input of user

```
while (enemy_hp > 0 && hp > 0) {
        System.out.println("It is your turn, attack (heavy or light) or try to block");
        int your_block_chance1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4); //Chance to block an attack
        int enemy_block_chance1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        String action = userInput.next();
```

When you type "heavy" in console

```
if (action.equals(attack)) {
```

"heavy" is not equals "attack" so it goes..

```
else if (action.equals(light)) {
```

"heavy" is not equals "light" so again condition is not true

You are going all the way down to:

```
        if (hp <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You failed");
        } else if (enemy_hp <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You won!");
        }
```

So it returns to the while loop and you can try typing again.

Your condition for "heavy" is inside of "light" condition:

```
else if (action.equals(light)) {
...
...
   } else if (action.equals(heavy)) {
```

I think your problem is that code is no readable. Try to use some IDE like intelij, eclipse to properly format your code.
I don't know if you are familiar with Object Oriented Programming but you should use more objects maybe something like Player, Enemy. You can also add some objects for specific attack types or block types, there is many options :)